# Solve the twin integrals.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> Solve the twin integrals: $$\int \frac{x\cos^2t}{\sqrt{x^2\cos^2 t+y^2\sin^2 t}}dt$$ $$\int \frac{y\sin^2t}{\sqrt{x^2\cos^2 t+y^2\sin^2 t}}dt$$

I tried to use the substitution of $u=x^2\cos^2 t+y^2\sin^2 t$  but it doesn't seems to work.

Then I tried
$$\int \:\frac{x\left(\frac{e^{it}+e^{-it}}{2}\right)^2}{\sqrt{x^2\left(\frac{e^{it}+e^{-it}}{2}\right)^2+y^2\left(\frac{e^{it}-e^{-it}}{2}\right)^2}}dt$$
And I simplified it to 
$$\int \:\:\frac{\left(e^{i2t}+e^{-i2t}\right)x+2x}{2\left(e^{i2t}+e^{-i2t}\right)\left(x^2+y^2\right)+4\left(x^2-y^2\right)}dt$$

> I am stuck again.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck once you'd tried it? Edit your question to say how.

Comment: It leads to an elliptic one.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need bounds if you want to get something truly meaningful, as I don't think your proposed integrand has an elementary antiderivative. That being said, consider the integral $\int \sqrt{x^2\cos^2t+y^2\sin^2t} \, dt$. An interesting observation is that your two integrals are the $x$ and $y$ partial derivatives of this integral (by the Leibniz Rule), so evaluating this alternative integral and then taking partials would allow you to evaluate both of your integrals.